# jquery toggle auto scroll on button click and mouse scroll - smoother auto scroll

Tags: jquery, autoscroll

I have a site that starts with auto scroll enabled but gives the user a few seconds to disable it or begin scrolling which would also disable it. I thought that I could just toggle the true/false but that doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure how to implement the mouse scroll event though. Here is the code I have for that:

```
var autoplay=true;

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        if  (autoplay)
             $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 22000);
        },2000);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".scrollToggle").click(function(){
            if(autoplay==true) {
                autoplay==false;
            } 
            else {
                autoplay==true;
            }
        });
    });
```

Also, does anyone know how I can make this auto scroll smoother?

UPDATE:
Thanks so much! This is awesome! Only issues are; 1) For some reason its not starting automatically on page load and 2) when toggled off, it starts back at the top (which isn't really too much of an issue), also 3) It seems like it gains speed as it scrolls down. Here are the other functions I am running, maybe there is something stopping it:

```
$(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
        $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
        $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
        $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});

        setTimeout (function () {
            scrollTo(0,0);
        }, 0);

    });

    var autoplay = true,
        root = $("html, body"),
        t = 24000, //overall duration for the animation, you can set this
        n = 0,
        d = 0;

    function scrollStart() {
        n = Date.now();//get the current time in ms
        t -= d;//the current duration minus the time already traverse
        root.animate({scrollTop: $(document).height() }, t);       
        autoplay = false;
    }

    function scrollStop() {
        //on stop instance, get the time already took to travel
        d = Date.now() - n;
        root.stop(true);
        autoplay = true;
    }

    $(".scrollToggle").click(function(){
        if(autoplay) {
            scrollStart();
            $("#onOff").text("OFF");
        } else {
            scrollStop();
            $("#onOff").text("ON");
        }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        autoplay = false;
    });  

    $(window).bind('resize', function(e)
    {
      if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
      window.RT = setTimeout(function()
      {
        this.location.reload(false); /* false to get page from cache */
      }, 100);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your toggle structure is okay but your operators are incorrect, it should be:

```
   $(".scrollToggle").click(function(){
        if(autoplay == true) {//or just if(autoplay) which is truthy
            autoplay = false;
        } 
        else {
            autoplay = true;
        }
    });
```

To handle the mouse scroll you can simply use the `scroll()` event, it handles both the scroll bar dragging and mousewheel scrolling:

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        autoplay = false;
    });
```

---

If you want a pause/resume functionality you can use `stop()` to pause then continue by resetting the animation.

```
function scrollStart(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 22000);
}

$(".scrollToggle").click(function(){
    if(autoplay==true) {
        scrollStart();
        autoplay=false;
    } else {
        $("html, body").stop(true);
        autoplay=true;
    }
});
```

However eventually when you toggle multiple times you'll see the next resume animation is somewhat slower compared to its initial. We can relate animation to speed wherein it has distance and time, with this solution right now the speed varies because it already traverse some distance but we are still giving it the same amount of time/duration. As speed is distance over time, to maintain the speed across every resume of the animation we should also calculate the reduced time.

```
var autoplay = true,
    root = $("html, body"),
    t = 8000, //overall duration for the animation, you can set this
    n = 0,
    d = 0;

function scrollStart() {
    n = Date.now();//get the current time in ms
    t -= d;//the current duration minus the time already traverse
    root.animate({scrollTop: $(document).height() }, t);       
    autoplay = false;
}

function scrollStop() {
    //on stop instance, get the time already took to travel
    d = Date.now() - n;
    root.stop(true);
    autoplay = true;
}

$(".scrollToggle").click(function(){
    if(autoplay) {
        scrollStart();
    } else {
        scrollStop();
    }
});
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cMJZ4/1/ , check out the console to see the time differential.

Comment: Thanks, the scroll event works but the button toggle needs to work at all times on the page. Currently it only works if you click on it before the auto scroll begins. Any idea how to add that in?

Comment: Also, if you turn it off, it doesn't turn back on.

Comment: I see, I've updated my answer. It's not a very good explanation but I'm hoping you'll get it :D

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
var autoplay=true;

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        if  (autoplay)
             $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 22000);
        },2000);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".scrollToggle").click(function(){
         $('html,body').queue([]).stop();

        });
    });
```

Comment: I believe you don't need the `queue()` there, `stop()` will do just fine and if you want to `clearqueue` you can just set `stop(true)`.

Comment: Thanks, how can I use this to turn auto scroll back on if the user clicks again?

Comment: You can dequeue the element by $('html,body').queue([]).dequeue();

Comment: I tried adding an IF statement to this but it didn't work :\ 

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".scrollToggle").click(function(){
    if(autoplay) {
     $("html,body").queue([]).stop();
     $("#onOff").text("OFF");
    } else {
     $("html,body").queue([]).dequeue();
     $("#onOff").text("ON");
    }
   });
  });

Answer (score 0):

How to not move from div (no scroll)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(target){
        var artz = document.getElementsByClassName('eds');
        var targ = document.getElementById(target);  
        var isVis = targ.style.display=='block';
        // hide all
        for(var i=0;i<artz.length;i++){
            artz[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        // toggle current
        targ.style.display = isVis?'none':'block';
        return false;
    }
</script>
```